# ThreeJS: Tweaking projection / raycasting

Tags: math, three.js, point, projection, raycasting

there is a very rough ThreeJS sketch with a cube at the Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) rotated with one edge to a viewer. Code gets some screen points from left/right edges, transforms them to 3D world coordinates and transpose further for their projections on the cube. By now I have set them by hand, but it could be done with THREE.Raycaster and the result is the same.

```
let m0 = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, edges.wtl.y, 100.0);
let m1 = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, edges.wtl.y, -100.0);
let ray0 = new THREE.Raycaster();
let dir = m1.clone().sub(m0.clone()).normalize();
ray0.set(m0, dir);
```

[image]

The initial setup looks fine, but if you rotate scene with OrbitControls you would notice that straight white lines don't match with red ones. **Despite the fact that the red lines are built correctly based on the camera FOV distortion** I need to tweak red dots in a way illustrated below.

[image]

Any ideas? Maybe I need to find screen coordinates for cube left/right edges and find its intersections with whose I am using just in the beginning of `calculateEdges()` and transform them back to world ones? It's a very clumsy solution and could be use as a last resort only.

```js
  THREE.OrbitControls = function ( object, domElement ) {

    this.object = object;
    this.domElement = ( domElement !== undefined ) ? domElement : document;

    // API

    this.enabled = true;

    this.center = new THREE.Vector3();

    this.userZoom = true;
    this.userZoomSpeed = 1.0;

    this.userRotate = true;
    this.userRotateSpeed = 1.0;

    this.userPan = true;
    this.userPanSpeed = 2.0;

    this.autoRotate = false;
    this.autoRotateSpeed = 2.0; // 30 seconds per round when fps is 60

    this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
    this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians

    this.minDistance = 0;
    this.maxDistance = Infinity;

    // 65 /*A*/, 83 /*S*/, 68 /*D*/
    this.keys = { LEFT: 37, UP: 38, RIGHT: 39, BOTTOM: 40, ROTATE: 65, ZOOM: 83, PAN: 68 };

    // internals

    var scope = this;

    var EPS = 0.000001;
    var PIXELS_PER_ROUND = 1800;

    var rotateStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var rotateEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var rotateDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

    var zoomStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var zoomEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var zoomDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

    var phiDelta = 0;
    var thetaDelta = 0;
    var scale = 1;

    var lastPosition = new THREE.Vector3();

    var STATE = { NONE: -1, ROTATE: 0, ZOOM: 1, PAN: 2 };
    var state = STATE.NONE;

    // events

    var changeEvent = { type: 'change' };


    this.rotateLeft = function ( angle ) {

        if ( angle === undefined ) {

            angle = getAutoRotationAngle();

        }

        thetaDelta -= angle;

    };

    this.rotateRight = function ( angle ) {

        if ( angle === undefined ) {

            angle = getAutoRotationAngle();

        }

        thetaDelta += angle;

    };

    this.rotateUp = function ( angle ) {

        if ( angle === undefined ) {

            angle = getAutoRotationAngle();

        }

        phiDelta -= angle;

    };

    this.rotateDown = function ( angle ) {

        if ( angle === undefined ) {

            angle = getAutoRotationAngle();

        }

        phiDelta += angle;

    };

    this.zoomIn = function ( zoomScale ) {

        if ( zoomScale === undefined ) {

            zoomScale = getZoomScale();

        }

        scale /= zoomScale;

    };

    this.zoomOut = function ( zoomScale ) {

        if ( zoomScale === undefined ) {

            zoomScale = getZoomScale();

        }

        scale *= zoomScale;

    };

    this.pan = function ( distance ) {

        distance.transformDirection( this.object.matrix );
        distance.multiplyScalar( scope.userPanSpeed );

        this.object.position.add( distance );
        this.center.add( distance );

    };

    this.update = function () {

        var position = this.object.position;
        var offset = position.clone().sub( this.center );

        // angle from z-axis around y-axis

        var theta = Math.atan2( offset.x, offset.z );

        // angle from y-axis

        var phi = Math.atan2( Math.sqrt( offset.x * offset.x + offset.z * offset.z ), offset.y );

        if ( this.autoRotate ) {

            this.rotateLeft( getAutoRotationAngle() );

        }

        theta += thetaDelta;
        phi += phiDelta;

        // restrict phi to be between desired limits
        phi = Math.max( this.minPolarAngle, Math.min( this.maxPolarAngle, phi ) );

        // restrict phi to be betwee EPS and PI-EPS
        phi = Math.max( EPS, Math.min( Math.PI - EPS, phi ) );

        var radius = offset.length() * scale;

        // restrict radius to be between desired limits
        radius = Math.max( this.minDistance, Math.min( this.maxDistance, radius ) );

        offset.x = radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
        offset.y = radius * Math.cos( phi );
        offset.z = radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );

        position.copy( this.center ).add( offset );

        this.object.lookAt( this.center );

        thetaDelta = 0;
        phiDelta = 0;
        scale = 1;

        if ( lastPosition.distanceTo( this.object.position ) > 0 ) {

            this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

            lastPosition.copy( this.object.position );

        }

    };


    function getAutoRotationAngle() {

        return 2 * Math.PI / 60 / 60 * scope.autoRotateSpeed;

    }

    function getZoomScale() {

        return Math.pow( 0.95, scope.userZoomSpeed );

    }

    function onMouseDown( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;
        if ( scope.userRotate === false ) return;

        event.preventDefault();

        if ( state === STATE.NONE )
        {
            if ( event.button === 0 )
                state = STATE.ROTATE;
            if ( event.button === 1 )
                state = STATE.ZOOM;
            if ( event.button === 2 )
                state = STATE.PAN;
        }
        
        
        if ( state === STATE.ROTATE ) {

            //state = STATE.ROTATE;

            rotateStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

        } else if ( state === STATE.ZOOM ) {

            //state = STATE.ZOOM;

            zoomStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

        } else if ( state === STATE.PAN ) {

            //state = STATE.PAN;

        }

        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );

    }

    function onMouseMove( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        event.preventDefault();

        
        
        if ( state === STATE.ROTATE ) {

            rotateEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
            rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart );

            scope.rotateLeft( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / PIXELS_PER_ROUND * scope.userRotateSpeed );
            scope.rotateUp( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / PIXELS_PER_ROUND * scope.userRotateSpeed );

            rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

        } else if ( state === STATE.ZOOM ) {

            zoomEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
            zoomDelta.subVectors( zoomEnd, zoomStart );

            if ( zoomDelta.y > 0 ) {

                scope.zoomIn();

            } else {

                scope.zoomOut();

            }

            zoomStart.copy( zoomEnd );

        } else if ( state === STATE.PAN ) {

            var movementX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
            var movementY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;

            scope.pan( new THREE.Vector3( - movementX, movementY, 0 ) );

        }

    }

    function onMouseUp( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;
        if ( scope.userRotate === false ) return;

        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );

        state = STATE.NONE;

    }

    function onMouseWheel( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;
        if ( scope.userZoom === false ) return;

        var delta = 0;

        if ( event.wheelDelta ) { // WebKit / Opera / Explorer 9

            delta = event.wheelDelta;

        } else if ( event.detail ) { // Firefox

            delta = - event.detail;

        }

        if ( delta > 0 ) {

            scope.zoomOut();

        } else {

            scope.zoomIn();

        }

    }

    function onKeyDown( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;
        if ( scope.userPan === false ) return;

        switch ( event.keyCode ) {

            /*case scope.keys.UP:
                scope.pan( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ) );
                break;
            case scope.keys.BOTTOM:
                scope.pan( new THREE.Vector3( 0, - 1, 0 ) );
                break;
            case scope.keys.LEFT:
                scope.pan( new THREE.Vector3( - 1, 0, 0 ) );
                break;
            case scope.keys.RIGHT:
                scope.pan( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ) );
                break;
            */
            case scope.keys.ROTATE:
                state = STATE.ROTATE;
                break;
            case scope.keys.ZOOM:
                state = STATE.ZOOM;
                break;
            case scope.keys.PAN:
                state = STATE.PAN;
                break;
                
        }

    }
    
    function onKeyUp( event ) {

        switch ( event.keyCode ) {

            case scope.keys.ROTATE:
            case scope.keys.ZOOM:
            case scope.keys.PAN:
                state = STATE.NONE;
                break;
        }

    }

    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', function ( event ) { event.preventDefault(); }, false );
    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false );
    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox
    window.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );
    window.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp, false );

};

THREE.OrbitControls.prototype = Object.create( THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype );
  
  let camera, scene, renderer, raycaster, controls, edges = {}, line0, line1, plane;

            let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            let windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                const container = document.createElement('div');
                document.body.appendChild(container);

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1024);
                camera.position.x = 0;
                camera.position.y = 0;
                camera.position.z = 64;
                
                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                edges.tl = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                edges.tr = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                edges.bl = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                edges.br = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                edges.wtl = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                edges.wtr = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                edges.wbl = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                edges.wbr = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                edges.width = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                edges.wwidth = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

                const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xCCCCCC, 0.4);
                scene.add(ambientLight);

                const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.8);
                camera.add(pointLight);
                scene.add(camera);

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
                controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2.0 -0.15;
                controls.maxPolarAngle =  Math.PI / 2.0 + 0.15;
                controls.minAzimuthAngle = -0.15;
                controls.maxAzimuthAngle = 0.15;
                controls.minDistance = 42.0; //.75;
                controls.maxDistance = 69.0;

                //cube
                let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(32, 32, 32);
                let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x00FFFF} );
                const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                cube.rotation.set(0.0, -Math.PI / 4.0, 0.0);
                cube.name = "cube";
                cube.updateMatrixWorld();
                scene.add(cube);

                //window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                render();

            }
    
            function render() {

                controls.update();

                calculateEdges()
        
                renderer.render(scene, camera);

            }

            function calculateEdges(){

                let toRemove = ["line0", "line1", "topLine", "bottomLine", "frame", "pointTM", "pointBM", "point00", "point01", "point10", "point11", "point20","point21", "point30", "point31", "point40", "point41"];

                toRemove.forEach((name_) => { if(scene.getObjectByName(name_) != undefined) { scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName(name_)); } })

                let distance = 0.0, w = 50;

                edges.tl.x = -1.0;
                edges.tl.y = -((windowHalfY - w)  / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
                edges.tl.z = 0.0;

                edges.width.x = ((2.0 * w) / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
                edges.width.y = -((windowHalfY - w)  / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
                edges.width.z = 0.0;

                edges.tr.x = (windowHalfX * 2.0 / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
                edges.tr.y = -((windowHalfY - w)  / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
                edges.tr.z = 0.0;

                edges.bl.x = -1.0;
                edges.bl.y = -((windowHalfY + w)  / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
                edges.bl.z = 0.0;

                edges.br.x = (windowHalfX * 2.0 / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
                edges.br.y = -((windowHalfY + w)  / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
                edges.br.z = 0.0;

                edges.tl.unproject(camera);
                edges.tl.sub(camera.position).normalize();
                distance = -camera.position.z / edges.tl.z;
                edges.wtl = edges.wtl.copy(camera.position).add(edges.tl.multiplyScalar(distance));

                edges.width.unproject(camera);
                edges.width.sub(camera.position).normalize();
                distance = -camera.position.z / edges.width.z;
                edges.wwidth = edges.wwidth.copy(camera.position).add(edges.width.multiplyScalar(distance));

                edges.tr.unproject(camera);
                edges.tr.sub(camera.position).normalize();
                distance = -camera.position.z / edges.tr.z;
                edges.wtr = edges.wtr.copy(camera.position).add(edges.tr.multiplyScalar(distance));

                edges.bl.unproject(camera);
                edges.bl.sub(camera.position).normalize();
                distance = -camera.position.z / edges.bl.z;
                edges.wbl = edges.wbl.copy(camera.position).add(edges.bl.multiplyScalar(distance));

                edges.br.unproject(camera);
                edges.br.sub(camera.position).normalize();
                distance = -camera.position.z / edges.br.z;
                edges.wbr = edges.wbr.copy(camera.position).add(edges.br.multiplyScalar(distance));

                const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0FFFFFF });

                const points0 = [edges.wtl, edges.wtr];
                let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points0);

                line0 = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
                line0.name = "line0";
                scene.add(line0);

                const points1 = [edges.wbl, edges.wbr];
                geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points1);

                line1 = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
                line1.name = "line1";
                scene.add(line1);

                const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.0, 8, 8);
                const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFFFFFF } );
                const sphereMaterial2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000 } );

                let p00 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wtl.x, edges.wtl.y, 0.0);
                let p01 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wbl.x, edges.wbl.y, 0.0);

                let p10 = new THREE.Vector3(-Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, edges.wtl.y, 0.0);
                let p11 = new THREE.Vector3(-Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, edges.wbl.y, 0.0);

                let p20 = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, edges.wtl.y, Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0);
                let p21 = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, edges.wbl.y, Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0);

                let p30 = new THREE.Vector3(Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, edges.wtl.y, 0.0);
                let p31 = new THREE.Vector3(Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, edges.wbl.y, 0.0);

                let p40 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wtr.x, edges.wtr.y, 0.0);
                let p41 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wbr.x, edges.wbr.y, 0.0);

                let sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
                sphere.position.set(p00.x, p00.y, p00.z);
                sphere.name = "point00";
                scene.add(sphere);

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
                sphere.position.set(p01.x, p01.y, p01.z);
                sphere.name = "point01";
                scene.add(sphere);

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial2);
                sphere.position.set(p10.x, p10.y, p10.z);
                sphere.name = "point10";
                scene.add(sphere);

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
                sphere.position.set(p20.x, p20.y, p20.z);
                sphere.name = "point20";
                scene.add(sphere);

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial2);
                sphere.position.set(p30.x, p30.y, p30.z);
                sphere.name = "point30";
                scene.add(sphere);

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial2);
                sphere.position.set(p11.x, p11.y, p11.z);
                sphere.name = "point11";
                scene.add(sphere);

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
                sphere.position.set(p21.x, p21.y, p21.z);
                sphere.name = "point21";
                scene.add(sphere);

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial2);
                sphere.position.set(p31.x, p31.y, p31.z);
                sphere.name = "point31";
                scene.add(sphere);

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
                sphere.position.set(p40.x, p40.y, p40.z);
                sphere.name = "point40";
                scene.add(sphere);

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
                sphere.position.set(p41.x, p41.y, p41.z);
                sphere.name = "point41";
                scene.add(sphere);

                const material2 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0FF0000 });

                let points = [p00, p10, p20, p30, p40];
                geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);

                let topLine = new THREE.Line(geometry, material2);
                topLine.name = "topLine";
                scene.add(topLine);

                points = [p01, p11, p21, p31, p41];
                geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);

                let bottomLine = new THREE.Line(geometry, material2);
                bottomLine.name = "bottomLine";
                scene.add(bottomLine);

                let pf0 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wtl.x + edges.wtl.distanceTo(edges.wwidth), p00.y, p00.z);
                let pf1 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wbl.x + edges.wtl.distanceTo(edges.wwidth), p01.y, p01.z);
                //let pf1 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wwidth.x * 2, p01.y, p01.z);

                points = [p00, pf0, pf1, p01, p00];
                geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);

                let frameLine = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
                frameLine.name = "frame";
                scene.add(frameLine);

            }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/106/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As is in the figure below,

1. consider a `Plane` made by `camera.position` and both end-points(`P00` and `P40`)
2. and move the points(`P10` and `P30`) to the intersection points of the plane and the edges.

Then, the points would align straight on the screen as expected.
[image: Align points in 3d space on the 2d screen using Ray-cast(three.js) - Obtaining intersection point of line and plane based on perspective projection mapping.]

For example, by using `ray.intersectPlane()`,

```
let p00 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wtl.x, edges.wtl.y, 0.0);
let p01 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wbl.x, edges.wbl.y, 0.0);

//let p10 = new THREE.Vector3(-Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, edges.wtl.y, 0.0);
//let p11 = new THREE.Vector3(-Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, edges.wbl.y, 0.0);
let p10 = new THREE.Vector3(-Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, 16.0, 0.0);
let p11 = new THREE.Vector3(-Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, -16.0, 0.0);

let p20 = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, edges.wtl.y, Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0);
let p21 = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, edges.wbl.y, Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0);

//let p30 = new THREE.Vector3(Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, edges.wtl.y, 0.0);
//let p31 = new THREE.Vector3(Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, edges.wbl.y, 0.0);
let p30 = new THREE.Vector3(Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, 16.0, 0.0);
let p31 = new THREE.Vector3(Math.sqrt(2.0) * 16.0, -16.0, 0.0);

let p40 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wtr.x, edges.wtr.y, 0.0);
let p41 = new THREE.Vector3(edges.wbr.x, edges.wbr.y, 0.0);

let nwt = p00.clone().sub(camera.position).cross(p40.clone().sub(camera.position)).normalize();
let nwb = p01.clone().sub(camera.position).cross(p41.clone().sub(camera.position)).normalize();
let planewt = new THREE.Plane(nwt, -nwt.dot(camera.position));
let planewb = new THREE.Plane(nwb, -nwb.dot(camera.position));

let r10 = new THREE.Ray(p10.clone(), p11.clone().sub(p10).normalize());
let r11 = new THREE.Ray(p11.clone(), p10.clone().sub(p11).normalize());
r10.intersectPlane(planewt, p10);
r11.intersectPlane(planewb, p11);
let r30 = new THREE.Ray(p30.clone(), p31.clone().sub(p30).normalize());
let r31 = new THREE.Ray(p31.clone(), p30.clone().sub(p31).normalize());
r30.intersectPlane(planewt, p30);
r31.intersectPlane(planewb, p31);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check your solution and if it's ok.